# Newlines are not added to the end of shell variable

Tags: linux, shell

I have a strange problem with my shell script:

```
read s          
q=`echo -e "$q\n\n$s"`
l=`echo $q|wc -c`
```

This runs in a loop and gets some text from stdin (actually from cgi, over the network). I also get the content-length from there.

The problem is that if s == "" then two newlines should be added to "q". This however does not happen and "l" (length) will become incorrect. If "s" is not empty then it works well.

Why doesn't it add the newlines to "q" if "s" is blank?

It can be verified like this:

```
p=asd; q=`echo -e "$p\n\n\n"`; echo $q
```

It does not print three newlines, whereas this does:

```
echo -e "asd\n\n\n"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `echo $q` will not print trailing newlines even if they are present.  You need quotes for that: `echo "$q"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo -e` implies you are using `bash`; use `printf -v` instead.

```
read s     
printf -v q '%s\n\n%s' "$q" "$s"
l=$(printf '%s' "$q" | wc -c)
```

When setting `l`, you probably don't want to count the newline added by `echo`, only the newlines already present in the value of `q`. You could use `echo -n` to suppress that newline, but try to avoid `echo` when possible.

Even simpler, you can just use

```
read s
q="$q

$s"
```

Either way, no command substitution that could potentially drop newlines is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> Why doesn't it add the newlines to "q" if "s" is blank?

Because this is just how command substitution works.

From [POSIX shell command substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03), emphasis mine:

> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command in a subshell environment (see Shell Execution Environment) and replacing the command substitution (the text of command plus the enclosing "$()" or backquotes) with the standard output of the command, **removing sequences of one or more <newline>s at the end of the substitution**.

Do not use `` backticks, use `$(..)` instead.

Moreover:

> echo $q

Results from unquoted variable expansions undergo word splitting. With default `IFS` multiple consecutive whitespaces (spaces, tabs and newlines) are word separators and the result of expansion is split into words. With default IFS you will always have exactly one newline in the output from `echo $q`, never more. Quote variable expansions: `$q`-> `"$q"` to preserve whitespaces.

Research command substitution, word splitting, filename expansion and quoting in shell context.

With bash, there is no need to use command substitution in your code at all, just assign to the variable with C-ANSI quoting:

```
q="$p"$'\n\n\n'"$s"
echo "$q"
# or better for debugging variable values:
declare -p q
```

Comment: If using a shell that does not support `$''` syntax, you can also simply assign a newline to `$n` (eg `n='\n'`, which does not render well in a comment) and write `q="$p$n$n$s"`